# How To Add Custom ModelValidatorProviders To Web API Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-validation

I'm moving some MVC code to Web API and I need to update my custom ModelValidatorProviders. It seems as though my validators can stay much the same only they should inherit the System.Web.Http.Validation namespace.

What I can't figure out is how to add the provider to Web API. When using MVC I can just add the following to my global.asax:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new CustomModelValidatorProvider());
```

How do I use the custom provider with Web API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This page [Configuring ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/configuring-aspnet-web-api) helped me answer my own question. Specifically this is what I ended up doing:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(ModelValidatorProvider), new CustomModelValidatorProvider());
```